# multiFragments under one tab in Tabhost

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-fragmentactivity, fragment-tab-host

i am creating an application using tabhost. I use this tab host in FRAGMENTACTIVITY.
under each tab i open Fragments.

But my requirement is

FragmentActivity contains a tabHost.
and  tab structure as given below.

Tab1 fragment1.1    (on click) Fragment1.2

Tab2 Fragment2.1

Tab3 Fragment3.1

i created mainActivity(FRAGMENTACTIVITY) using this tutorial

http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/

but i didn't get any idea to open another fragment under 1st tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();
    fragment1.2 fragment = new fragment1.2();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.tabcontent, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: yaa almost fine... my fragment 1.2 is a webView. i successfully load this webView. but there is another problem.
we move to fragment1.2 from fragment1.1 and now i click on the 2nd tab. the web view and content of fragment2.1 also displayed in screen

Comment: it si because that.. we write this code in fragment1.1 and when tab changed.... its not detaching the old  one.